# Tap event in Windows Phone Developer Tools

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Surely the event handler "Tap" or "DoubleTap or "Hold" is supported only in WP 7.1 and therefore it is not in Windows Phone Developer Tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use them in WP7.0, you could use the [WP7 silverlight toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/60291) although I don't see a reason to build apps for WP7.0 now.

**Update**

Link to [WP7.1 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27570)

Comment: Better download WPDT 7.1 Beta?

Comment: Added the link to the WP7.1 sdk, don't think it's beta anymore. I think almost every existing device is now updated to mango, and all new devices already have mango installed. So yes, better start developing for 7.1